# How can I supply a heredoc to podman run?

Tags: shell, here-document, podman

When I run `buildah`, I typically use a heredoc,

```bash
ctr=$(buildah from alpine:3);

buildah run $ctr sh -- <<EOF
  apk update;
  apk add git;
EOF

buildah commit $ctr heredoc_demo;
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with podman, I get an error like this,

> WARN[0000] The input device is not a TTY. The --tty and --interactive flags might not work properly

Which you can get with,

```
❯ podman run -ti alpine:3 sh -- <<EOF
  echo 42
EOF
WARN[0000] The input device is not a TTY. The `--tty` and `--interactive` flags might not work properly
```

Or nothing happens as with

```bash
podman run alpine:3 sh <<EOF
```

What is the right invocation here?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, note:

- do not use `-t` (`--tty`)
- do use an `-i` (`--interactive`)

This looks like this,

```bash
podman run -i heredoc_demo sh -- <<EOF
    echo "Hello world";
EOF
```

Or,

```bash
cat <<EOF | podman run -i heredoc_demo sh -
    echo "Hello world";
EOF
```